# Direct Print receipt/ cheque only selecting print button on angular 7

Tags: javascript, html, printing, ssrs-2012, angular7

I'm using angular 7 to create simple system. When click print button automatically open popup window and show to select printer. But I don't want to select printers like that and want to print some data within system silently. (silent printing). Can I pragmatically enable silent printing on browsers.

Reason is cheques and receipts cannot allow print more copies. Also Don't need to allow change default settings of the receipt.

Comment: And... what does this have to do with SSRS?

Comment: I’m using ssra report generation tool to design some receipt designs